# Currently active Research Areas in Topological Groups

Tags: topological-groups, paper-request, research

I have done my Master's degree in mathematics and currently I am doing Ph.D. in mathematics in India. I have completed my course work and my supervisor works in **Topological Groups**. He suggests me some books for reading like

> 1. Topological Groups and Related Structures by  A. V. Arkhangelʹskiĭ
> 2. Introduction to Topological Groups by Taqdir Hussain
> 3. Topology: An introduction with applications to Topological Groups by G. McCarty.

I have read the basics about topological groups from all these books.
First book is somehow difficult to understand, so I mostly studied in other two books.

Now I want to read some research papers and want to have some research idea in this topic.

Please help me in what research papers should I read and what are the active research areas in this topic.

Comment: Did you ask your supervisor for the same?

Comment: Sumit, I think your question will be better if you allow people to give advises not only to beginners, but to all people who are interested in this topic.

Comment: One thing you can do is see questions here on MO with topological groups tag.. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/topological-groups Currently there are 415 questions excluding your question.. You can have a quick look at titles and see if any of them is interesting... if you find title interesting or familiar, you can then go to that question and see if you can understand something...

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov okay..thanx

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yeah, he suggested me the paper [Introduction to topological groups by MikhailTkačenko](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864198000510) but I also want to know other papers and active research areas in this topic.

Comment: @SumitMittal You can start reading that paper, If you face some difficulty, you can ask here then according to that users here can suggest you some papers where it is mentioned in a better way... You start with **a** paper... just knowing what are all papers in that topic may not be useful..  If one paper is difficult to read you might think of trying another and it might waste some time..  This is just my personal opinion.. You can also see some references in that paper..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Do you work in topological groups or have u studied about them?? what are the current research areas in this topic??

Comment: @SumitMittal There are at least three quite independent currently active areas of research in topological groups: 1. Topology of top. groups --- the books listed by you. 2. Analysis on locally compact groups -- search for "abstract harmonic analysis". 3. "Dynamics on infinite-dimensional groups" -- see Pestov's book with that title and more recent papers that cite it.